# Solving equations

Tags: calculus, integration

I seem to have forgotten how to solve equations, I was reading an example in my book and couldn't follow along. I tried googling factoring methods, using the quadratic formula, but im not getting what the book is saying.

The question is trying to find the area between $x^2 -x -2$ and $4-x^2$ in the closed interval $(-2,3)$. The first step to finding the signed area is finding the points where the graphs intersect so the x values. The book sets the two equations above equal to each other and comes up with $x=-3/2$ and $x=2$. I have done this before a million times, but for some reason I am in a rut. Help Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the two equations equal to eachother.

$$x^2-x-2 = 4-x^2$$
$$\text{Move everything to one side}$$
$$x^2-x-2-4+x^2 = 0$$
$$2x^2-x-6 = 0$$

Find two numbers that **multiply** to $-12$, **add** to $-1$. Those numbers are $x=3,-4$.

But, since the degree of the quadratic's main term is $2$, and not $1$, we are **not done!** The answers are **not** $x=-3,4$.

So, $$2x^2-x-6 = 0$$
$$\text{Replace the $x$ term with the factors}$$
$$2x^2-6+3x-4x = 0$$
$$2x^2-4x+3x-6 = 0$$
$$2x(x-2)+3(x-2) = 0$$

Our solutions are $2x+3=0$, $x-2=0$.

So, $x_1=-3/2, x_2=2$

Comment: do you know what this method of factoring is called?

Comment: Ahh I have found out this is called the AC method!

Comment: My teacher always called it the "product sum" method of factoring

Answer (score 1):

Try plot the functions, i can must see that you need make 3 integrals (remember that you're calculating an area, the answer is a positive number).

The first integral you need is:
$$A_1 = \int_{x=-2}^{x=-\frac{3}{2}} (x^2-x-2)-(4-x^2)   dx=\frac{23}{24}$$

The second integral is:
$$A_2 = \int_{x=-\frac{3}{2}}^{x=2} (4-x^2)-(x^2-x-2)   dx=\frac{343}{24}$$

And the third integral is:
$$A_3 = \int_{x=2}^{x=3} (x^2-x-2)-(4-x^2)   dx=\frac{25}{6}$$

The area is $A_1+A_2+A_3=\frac{233}{12}$

PDT: Check why i've changed the order of the functions in the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Quadratic formula perhaps? \begin{eqnarray*}
x^2 - x - 2 &=& 4-x^2 \\
2x^2 - x -6 &=& 0 \\
\therefore x &=& \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \\
&=& \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4(2)(-6)}}{2(2)} \\
&=& \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+48}}{4} \\
&=& \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{49}}{4} \\
&=& \frac{1 \pm 7}{4} \\
&=& 2 \ \text{or} \ \frac{-6}{4} \\
&=& 2 \ \text{or} \ -\frac{3}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

up vote
0
down vote
favorite

I seem to have forgotten how to solve equations, I was reading an example in my book and couldn't follow along. I tried googling factoring methods, using the quadratic formula, but im not getting what the book is saying.

The question is trying to find the area between x^2 -x -2 and 4-x^2 in the closed interval (-2,3). The first step to finding the signed area is finding the points where the graphs intersect so the x values. The book sets the two equations above equal to each other and comes up with x=-3/2 and x=2. I have done this before a million times, but for some reason I am in a rut. Help Please!
calculus integration
shareciteeditflag

asked 8 mins ago
Shanen
516

add a comment
Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.
Your Answer

```
    Links Images Styling/Headers Lists Blockquotes Preformatted HTML
    advanced help »
```

community wiki

Where the graphs cross, i.e., y = x^2 - x - 2 and y = 4 - x^2 , the two y-values will be equal;  i.e.,  x^2 - x - 2 = 4 - x^2 .
So 2x^2 - x - 6 = 0
The LHS has fairly simple factors; so proceed as follows (or complete a square, or use the quadratic formula).
(2x + 3) (x - 2) = 0
So  2x + 3 = 0  or  x -2 = 0,
    x = -3/2  or  2 .
Nest, note that for  x < -3/2 ,  x^2 - x - 2 > 4 - x^2 ;
for  -3/2 < x < 2 , x^2 - x - 2 < 4 - x^2 ;
and for  x > 2 ,  x^2 - x - 2 > 4 - x^2  again.
If you want the net area between these two curves, you must consider the integral of the difference separately for these three intervals.
But if you want the signed area, just take the interval -2 < x < 3 in one go  --  after deciding which curve is to be considered "on top".
  ∫ (2x^2 - x - 6) dx
= 2x^3 / 3 - x^2 / 2 - 6x
Between  -2  and  3 , this yields:
  18 - 9/2 - 18 - (16/3 - 2 - 12)
= 25/6
Or: (-2, -3/2) : -9/4 - 9/8 + 9 - (18 - 9/2 - 18) = 135/8
    (-3/2, 2) : -(16/3 -2 - 12 - (-9/4 - 9/8 + 9) = 343/24
    (2, 3) :     18 - 9/2 - 18 - (16/3 -2 - 12)   = 29/6
Net area: 866/24 = 433/12